# django allauth redirect to another page after email verification

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have this issue: I need to redirect to another page when email verification is confirmed and login for the first time after the email verification. I tried to configure this in setting.py, but didn't work.

My settings.py:

```
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = os.getenv('schools/form-school')
```

the url in urls.py is: `path('form-school', views.school_list_view, name = 'schools' ),`

if you have any clue on how to resolve this please comment your ideas, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL` you have to specify the URL or named URL pattern associated to the view you want to display. Sometimes knowing the full URL can be tricky and using the named URL pattern comes in handy as it let's you reference your views without having to care about the absolute path where you defined the url. In your case the URL pattern is the string `schools` that is set as the value the parameter `name`.

It should be enough to set that as:

```py
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = "schools"
```

Note that [`os.getenv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv) is used when you need to retrieve the value for an environment variable. This is kinda weird in this situation and I doubt that your project is storing the URL/named URL pattern for a particular view in an environment variable (also environment variables with characters other than numbers, letters and underscore may not be well interpreted).